# check for each item in an array into a string and replace those items along with some html

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have mysqli array of names

```
$names=$row['names']; // in the column names , i have "Abu bakkar siddique,Kim hon tae"
```

and a string

```
 $string='Abu bakkar siddique and Kim hon tae meets the same result';
```

after exploding i got like

```
$nameEx=explode(',', $names);

foreach($nameEx as $name){
   if (strpos($string, $name)) {
     $new[]=str_replace($name,'<a href="#">'.$name.'</a>', $string);           
    }
}
$results = implode(", ",$new);
echo $results;
```

Out is:

```html
<a href="#">Abu bakkar siddique</a> and Kim hon tae meets the same result, Abu bakkar siddique and <a href="#">Kim hon tae</a> meets the same result
```

How to get

```html
<a href="#">Abu bakkar siddique</a> and <a href="#">Kim hon tae</a> meets the same result
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($nameEx as $name){
    if (strpos($string, $name) !== false) {
        $string=str_replace($name,'<a href="#">'.$name.'</a>', $string);
    }
}
echo $string;
```

You replace each name by one iteration.

Also you need to check if strpos return 0 (position of first occurrence) or false (no occurrences). In your example first name wouldn't be replaced because strpos would return 0 and if-statement would pass this iteration.

**Updated:**

It's not very beautiful but it works. First, you get names and sort it by length. Then, replace names with "markers". And finally replace markers with your actual strings.

```
$names = "Abu bakkar,Abu bakkar siddique,Kim hon tae";
$string = "Abu bakkar siddique, Abu bakkar and Kim hon tae meets the same result. Abu bakkar is name for test";

$nameEx = explode(',', $names);

usort($nameEx, function($a, $b) {
    if (strlen($a) < strlen($b)) { return 1; } elseif (strlen($a) == strlen($b)) { return 0; } else { return -1; }
});

foreach($nameEx as $key => $name) {
    $string = str_replace($name, "#".$key."#", $string);
}

foreach($nameEx as $key => $name) {
    $string = str_replace("#".$key."#", "<a href='#'>".$name.'</a>', $string);
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: brother, between similar names, these codes find the shorter match, like a cautions made by Random, if the array has Abu bakkar and Abu bakkar siddique together, it takes Abu bakkar rather than Abu bakkar siddique, although the best matches with Abu bakkar siddique....your kind attention please.

Comment: Nice update. Still get a problem if one's name is `#1#`, but kinda tricky one... Upvoted ;)

Comment: Sure, it's not the best solution. But it would works in common cases

Comment: @2kai, Thank you bro, I was away from computer. and sorry for being late to mark as solved. I did upvote for you also..

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this :

```
foreach($nameEx as $name){
   if (strpos($string, $name) !== false) {
     $string=str_replace($name,'<a href="#">'.$name.'</a>', $string);           
    }
}
echo $string;
```

but just be careful with such a method if a name contains an other... for instance if one's name is `Abu bakkar` and an other is `Abu bakkar siddique`

Comment: Brother, is there anyother method to avoid these?  this is excellent, thank you.

Comment: You need to check if strpos return 0 (position of first occurrence) or false (no occurrences).

Comment: @2kai : I edited, thx. @user159 : it would be kinda harder. The easiest way i see is to order your name list by size, and start from the shorter name. A larger name will not find the occurence (if a shorter name is found) since a `<a>` tag will be added into the name; So when the code will look for `Abu bakkar siddique`, he will only find `<a href="#">Abu bakkar</a> siddique`, so name not found

Comment: @Random why do you want to start with shorter names? First you need to find long names and replace it, don't you?

Comment: @2kai if you start with long name, you will first make the output `<a href="#">Abu bakkar siddique</a>`, then you search for `Abu bakkar`, you will find it, and make the output `<a href="#"><a href="#">Abu bakkar</a> siddique</a>`, which may be a problem... you can't tag both names, you have to choose which one you link, and the shortest one makes less problems. But it can be less user-friendly maybe...

Comment: @Random In code below I have implemented way which solve this problem. Also we can try to use regular expressions to find long names instead of short names correctly.